# Using curl to bring search results from external site

Tags: php, curl

I have 2 sites, one main, one external. On the main site, I am using Lucene to search through it. The problem is, I am trying to also search through the external site.

The Form action for the external site:

```
<form action="https://secure.bcchf.ca/SuperheroPages/searchResults.cfm?Event=WOT" method="post" name="search_tribute" >
```

I've tried to use curl, but it only brings up the search form without actually doing the search (the field is empty as well).

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://secure.bcchf.ca/SuperheroPages/searchResults.cfm?Event=WOT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, tname='hello');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Any tips?

I don't have access to the form action since it's on an external site. All i have is a form that links to it when I submit it.

Comment: You'll likely need to include more fields in the post, also search='hello' doesn't seem like valid syntax. Depending on the site you may also need to set the referrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://secure.bcchf.ca/SuperheroPages/searchResults.cfm?Event=WOT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("teamName" => "hello", "searchType" => "team"));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Can you try this?
I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be teamName instead of tName

Comment: Thanks, but same problem as before.  It goes to the search result page, but still nothing is searched. The form disappears too.

Ya, i know it was teamName, but i kinda rushed when i posted here.

Comment: OMG, did you just added the searchtype? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yeah, that's all I added. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try just putting it into an array.
as that will be the variable the $_POST checks on the other side

and just checked your link, its teamName for the field

```
$fields = array("teamName"=>"julia");
```

Then..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

So your complete code is...

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init("https://secure.bcchf.ca/SuperheroPages/searchResults.cfm?Event=WOT");
 $fields = array("teamName"=>"julia");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 var_dump($output);
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

Comment: search_tribut e is not the name of the form element

Comment: There's actually only one input field, which is named "tname". When i add in the URL , it goes to the search result page, but still nothing is searched. Also, the form dissappears..

Comment: So you tried it by passing 'tname' in the array, like I have above now?

Comment: Yes, i've changed search to tname.

Comment: and youre absolutely positive its a POST not a GET?

Comment: Positive. I've posted the form action.

Comment: and what happens if you var_dump($output), not echo it

Comment: string(16243) followed by " .  So the search is getting the string i think, but it's returning a blank.

Comment: and does 16243 actually return results if you just search the site manually?

Comment: It's a post, so I can't search for it manually in the URL. I don't know how to structure it.

Comment: Go to the actual site...I thought it was an external site

Comment: I tried searching a bunch of things, nothing comes up....then I tried 'Julia' and that worked......so put that in your script and see if you get results......I changed my code above to reflect teamName and Julia....try my code now

Comment: That is the external site. THe actual site is here: https://www.bcchf.ca/. 

To search for the stuff in the external site, you can't use the actual site form, but the form in the Tribute page only.

Comment: Well I can get there just fine, and search just fine....???  Did you try my code with the updates......it should work....it works for me

Comment: It is still blank unfortunately. Valid search words aren't going through either.

Comment: Did it work when you curl, or when you did the search on the website?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for me.. But when i added the search type, it worked, as stated below.

Thank you the help

Answer (score 0):

Most search engine use `GET` and not `POST` .. you can try

```
// asumption
$_POST['search'] = "hello";

// Return goole Search Result
echo curlGoogle($_POST['search']);

function curlGoogle($keyword) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' . urlencode($keyword) . '&btnG=Google+Search&meta=');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Or if you want post then

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("search"=>"hello"));
```

Comment: The form is using Post in this case only

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is not valid syntax, it does not compile.

So if this is really what you have, your problem is that your file generates a fatal error.

That being said, this question is hard to answer since we don't know the site you want to grab your search results from.

Try modifying your line like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "search=hello");
```

or alternatively

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("search" => "hello");
```

Maby it will work, however it may be that more post data is required or that the element name is not correct.

You have to look at the form or try making a request and look at it with chromes developer tools or firebug.

Also there are a number of ways for external sites to prevent what you are doing, altough evertything can be worked around somehow.

Assuming that is not the case, I hope i could help you.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried putting it in an array, but the search page still remains blank.

Comment: in that case you have to further examine the post request being sent when requesting search results properly

Comment: I can't really examine it though, as i don't have access to the external site and how it parses the search input.

Comment: quote from my answer "you have to look at the form or try making a request and look at it with chromes developer tools or firebug.

"